# Why two values are compared as a string?

Tags: php, validation, types

I have problem I can't resolve for two days. I want compare two values representing year. First is a string submitted by user - contain only 4 digits. Second one is a string from `date('Y')` function, also 4 digits. I want check if one year i grater than another. But result of comparison is true if $string has more characters than result of date function. Even if I convert both strings to integer. I've also tried conversion using `intval` function. I've checked `gettype()` on both values in both cases just before comparison and they are the same type. Funny because if I put this code to phpfiddle it works like I want.

```
$string = '2020';
$isTooBig = $string > date('Y');

$isTooBig1 = (int)$string > (int)date('Y');
//In this case $isTooBig is boolean with 0 value;
```

Full code:

```
function whatIsWrong( $type, $string ) {
    $comma = '';
    $json = '';
    if ( $type == 'year' ) {
        $yearOverLimit = $string > date('Y') && strlen($string) == 4; //problem is here
        $fieldIsEmpty = strlen( $string ) == 0;
        $charIsWrong = !preg_match( '/^\d{4}$/', $string ) && !strlen($string) == 0;
        $json .= ' [';
        if ( $fieldIsEmpty ) {
            if ( $yearOverLimit || $charIsWrong ) {
                $comma = ', ';
            } else {
                $comma = '';
            }
            $json .= '{"message": "Year can\'t be empty"}'.$comma;
        }
        if ( $yearOverLimit ) {
            if ( $charIsWrong ) {
                $comma = ', ';
            } else {
                $comma = '';
            }
            $json .= '{"message": "Year must be between 1870-'.date('Y').'"}'.$comma;
        }
        if ( $charIsWrong ) {
            $json .= '{"message": "Year must be 4-digit"}';
        }
        $json .= ']';
    }
    return $json;
}
```

Comment: Why not use strtotime? That is the very reason that function exist. And creating your own jsonstring is not recommended. Use json_encode

Comment: Use DateTime comparison or convert those dates using strtotime. It should work.

Comment: Hi, in order to compute difference between two dates I think strtotime is the best guess here

$timeStamp1=strtotime('1 December 2022');#Your date input goes here
$differenceInSecondsBetweenTwoDates=$timeStamp1 - strtotime('1January 2020');
then if the difference is positive .. the date is in 2020 or above

Comment: If the first string contains 4 year digits plus some more characters appended, and the second string contains that same year digits only, when you compare the two the first one will be > than the second one. That's only logic and that's what string comparison is about. 
Casting to an int won't be a real solution (as the input could be 4 year digit plus one or more digits appended). But substringing the first 4 characters from the input probably will be... thus, make sure to compare 4 digit year string to 4 digit year string... eg: $string = substr($string, 0, 4);

Comment: @Werner Is input 4 or more digit is checked by preg_match and stored in $charIsWrong variable. Substringing may be confusing, as someone type by mystake one more 0 ('20012'), year will be different than desired. I simply don't understand why when I want compare (int)$string > (int)date('Y') it won't work in my function. As I mention, on phpfiddle working properly.

Comment: Next day... :-) When doesn't it work? With what input? 

Your code runs fine on PHP Version 5.4.25 also with         
$yearOverLimit = ( (int)$string > (int)date('Y') ) && strlen($string) == 4; 
on the line indicated where the problem is

Comment: also seems to run ok on PHP 7.0.32... not testing extensively though.

Comment: @Werner thanks for reply.:) When I input four digit year, no matter how big, $yearOverLimit is always false. Should be true because all numbers above current year should trigger if($yearOverLimit) block. Why comparison (int)$string > (int)date('Y') return only true if input is more than 4 digits.

Comment: $string='2018': $yearOverLimit is false.
Result of `$string > date('Y') && strlen($string) == 4` will be false. 
Why - 1st condition is NOT met, 2nd condition is ($string's length is indeed 4). 
But both need to be true for the result to be true (it's an AND).

$string = '20180': $yearOverLimit is still false.
Only first condition is met, second is not (for $string length is 5)

So, assigning `$string > date('Y') && strlen($string) == 4`  to variable $yearOverLimit will put false into it. 

Hence $yearOverLimit will only be true if $input > 2018 (curr yr) and 4 digits only

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for your clue about json_encode, it's much simplier.

Comment: @Werner I know what was wrong. Problem was in another function. Sorry for confusion and thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

@Werner said:"

> Hence `$yearOverLimit` will only be true if `$string > 2018 (curr yr)` and 4 digits only.

I know, it should be, it's my intention. But its not in my editor (vim) and don't know why.
`(int)$string > (int)date('Y')`  (without `strlen`) returns `false` if year is any of YYYY, return `true` if YYYYY or more. I'm stupid. Maybe it's PHP version differences?